# Why does my loop not work when I don't include this variable in a function?

Tags: c, char, return-value, do-while, conditional-operator

I'm writing a program that keeps prompting the user to write something until they write "done."

If I don't include `continueFlag` in the ternary operator of a function (last line), my do/while loop only runs once. How come? Wouldn't the result be the same if we're only checking the flag that checks for matching letters (quitFlag)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int checkWord(char userInput[]);

int main()
{
  int flag = 0;
  char userInput[30];

  do
  {
    printf("Speak: ");
    scanf("%s", userInput);
    flag = checkWord(userInput);

  } while (flag == 0);

  return 0;
}

int checkWord(char userInput[])
{
  char quitWord[5] = "done";
  int continueFlag = 0;
  int quitFlag = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    if (quitWord[i] != userInput[i])
    {
      continueFlag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      quitFlag = 1;
    }
  }

  return (quitFlag == 1 /* && continueFlag == 0 */) ? 1 : 0; // ternary operator
}
```

Comment: This `quitWord[i] != userInput[i])` checks pointers, not strings themselves. Use `strcmp`.

Comment: There's a function `strcmp()` in `string.h` to compare strings. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Haris unfortunately, since im in an intro/basic class, we cannot use libraries for now

Comment: And the `checkword` function is unnecessary. Just call `strcmp()` directly in `main()`. You can even use it as the loop condition.

Comment: And you do not make use of `continueflag` anywhere in your code. Why is it there?

Comment: @Haris my instrutor told us to write a function. we're practicing writing functions this week

Comment: @fukanchik `quitWord[i]` and `userInput[i]` are `char`s, not pointers.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't understand what the function is doing. You assign 1 to `continueflag` if the characters are not equal. It should be the other way around? And there no need to alternate between `true` and `false` in the ternary operator. Just write `return quitflag == 1;`

Comment: @Haris, i did that. it didn't work.

Comment: Your check is wrong. it will set `quitFlag` even if any single letter matches, not just when the whole word matches.

Comment: Testing `continueflag` in the ternary can't affect the number of times that the loop runs, since the test is *after* the loop.

Comment: Please edit your question when you change the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use an infinite loop and `break` instead all those flags.  That way you repeat yourself less.
2. Check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized data.
3. Use `strcmp()` or failing that implement a suitable replacement `my_strcmp()`.
4. The function name `checkWord()` is ambiguous.  What does it mean that a check was successful?  Is success 0 or 1?
5. Always pass a maximum field width to `scanf()` when reading a string to avoid buffer overflows.  I use a pair of macros here but at this point it's also ok to hard-code 29 in the format string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define USER_INPUT_LEN 29
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    while(*s1 && *s2 && *s1++ == *s2++);
    return *s2 - *s1;
}

int main() {
    char userInput[USER_INPUT_LEN + 1];
    for(;;) {
        printf("Speak: ");
        if(scanf("%" str(USER_INPUT_LEN) "s", userInput) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            break;
        }
        if(!my_strcmp(userInput, "done"))
            break;

    }
}
```

and example run:

```
Speak: test
Speak: do
Speak: done2
Speak: done
```

Comment: A comment says they're not allows to use built-in string functions like `strcmp()`.

Comment: @Barmar I will remind op to update question when they subsequently change their requirements.  Added a strcmp() implementation.  I can't help feeling it's a disservice teaching people to not use standard functions.

Answer (score 1):

`quitflag` is 1 if any of the characters match.

`continueflag` is 1 if any of the characters do *not* match.

The whole string will be equal if you found at least one matching character and didn't find any non-matching characters. That condition is represented in code with `quitflag == 1 && continueflag == 0`.

If you remove `continueflag` from the ternary, you're just testing whether there's at least one match, but not that all of them match.

You don't really need `quitflag` at all. As long as there are no non-matching characters, the strings match. So you can just use

```
return continueflag == 0;
```

You can do it without the variables at all. Just return false when you find a non-matching character, and return true if you make it through the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if ((quitWord[i] != userInput[i]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Because op hard-codes 4 as the length of the string if `userInput` starts with done" it will return 1.  Probably not correct.

Comment: I know, I'm not going to try to fix all their logic. They wanted to know why they needed the variable in the condition, I explained that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets `quitFlag = 1;` if any letter does match, and it sets `continueFlag = 1;` if any letter doesn't match. Therefore, `quitFlag==1` means at least one letter matches.

`quitFlag==1 && continueFlag==0` means at least one letter matches *and* none of the letters don't match, which is the same as saying they all match.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `quitFlag` is set to `1` if at least one character is present in the both strings in the same position.

```
if (quitWord[i] != userInput[i])
{
  continueFlag = 1;
}
else
{
  quitFlag = 1;
}
```

So if at least one character is present in the both strings in the same position then the function `checkWord` returns 1 and the do-while loop is interrupted. Otherwise the function returns 0 and the do-while loop continues its iterations.

So your statement

> If I don't include continueFlag in the ternary operator of a function
> (last line), my do/while loop only runs once. How come?

in general is wrong because the user can enter a string neither character of which is equal to the character in the string `"done"` in the same position because in this case the function `checkWord` returns 0.

This return statement

```
return (quitFlag == 1 && continueFlag == 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
```

returns `1` when all `4` characters of the strings are equal each other.

Opposite to the above return statement this return statement

```
return (quitFlag == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;
```

returns 1 when at least one character is present in the both strings in the same position.

But in any case your function is wrong at least because the user can pass to the function that contains more than 4 characters as for example `"donealready"`.

Using your approach with a loop the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
int checkWord( const char userInput[] )
{
    const char *quitWord = "done";

    const char *p = quitWord;

    while ( *p != '\0' && *p == *userInput )
    {
        ++p;
        ++userInput;
    }

    return *p == *userInpit;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
do
{
    printf( "Speak: " );
    scanf( "%29s", userInput );
} while ( !checkWord( userInput ) );
```